# Add project to an existing Monodevelop (Mono Touch) solution

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Where is the command/button/dialog to add a project to an existing mono touch solution?

e.g. I have a MonoTouch App and I want to add a class library to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if my IMac was not responding in the normal fashion for CTRL Click.  Got around this with double click to get to context menu

Comment: Same here, couldn't get CTRL click to work. Nor double click. I had to plugin in a mouse with a right button.